# boost specific words in specific documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can i boost specific words in specific documents in elasticsearch ?

for example in the following documents i want to boost words in "goodwords" field using the weight field which is calculated based on user search logs and result clicks.

```
** Document 1 **
{
    "title": "divergent",
    "year": "2014",
    "goodwords": [
        { "word": "scifi", "weight": 1.5 },
        { "word": "future", "weight": 1.1 }
    ]
}

** Document 2 **
{
    "title": "insurgent",
    "year": "2015",
    "goodwords": [
        { "word": "scifi", "weight": 0.8 },
        { "word": "future", "weight": 1.5 },
        { "word": "fiction", "weight": 1.8 }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the above mentioned query we have query time boosting and index time boosting.Mostly of the cases query time boosting compared to index time boosting.
For the above mentioned case you need change mapping.So I will provide the link for you and let me know if you have any issues.

See the [`boost` mapping parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) in the Elasticsearch documentation.

Comment: boosting specific fields is easy. what i want is to boost some specific values or keywords in a document. for example the keyword 'scifi' should be boosted with weight of 1.5 in the first document and 0.8 in the second and maybe not boosted at all in some other document ..

Comment: Got it but for particular key in the document we can boost while mapping it self and it is not possible  to specify each and every document.